# MySQL Sub-Queries Simplifying

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables: `Races` and `RacesTimes`, I want to extract all from `Races` and from `RacesTimes` only `Finisher` and `Time`, only the best `RacesTimes.TotalTime` (ordered ASC with LIMIT 1) from each `RaceID` (a column from `RacesTimes`).

So the result would be:
`Races.*`, `RacesTimes.Finisher`, `RacesTimes.Time`

This is what I made:

```
SELECT 
    Races.*, 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            `TotalTime` 
        FROM 
            `RacesTimes` 
        WHERE 
            `RaceID` = Races.ID 
        ORDER BY 
            `TotalTime` ASC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) AS `BestTime`, 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            `Time` 
        FROM 
            `RacesTimes` 
        WHERE 
            `RaceID` = Races.ID 
        ORDER BY
            `TotalTime` ASC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) AS `BestTimeS`, 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            `Finisher` 
        FROM 
            `RacesTimes` 
        WHERE 
            `RaceID` = Races.ID 
        ORDER BY 
            `TotalTime` ASC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) AS `BestFinisher` 
FROM `Races`
```

It is extracting corectly all, but the query is way too long, can't it be simplified ? I think the simplified version uses LEFT JOIN or other thing like that, I don't know how to use queries with JOIN.

Comment: Create an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/). That way, we have a better way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The approach here is to aggregate RaceTimes by race.  The trick is to get the finisher with the minimum time.

MySQL offers a solution for this, by using `group_concat()` and `substring_index()` in a clever way.  `group_concat()` takes an `order by argument`, so it can order the results by the time.  Then the best finisher is in the first position.

The SQL looks like this:

```
select r.*, rtr.mintt as TotalTime, rtr.Finisher
from Races r join
     (select RaceId, MIN(TotalTime) as mintt,
             substring_inde(group_concat(finisher separator ',' order by totaltime), 1) as Finisher
      from RaceTimes rt
      group by RaceId
     ) rtr
     on rtr.RaceId = r.id
```

Comment: It is still pretty long, it can't be shorter ?